# Multiple option selects to create unique shopping cart SKU

Tags: javascript, paypal

Is there a way of inserting a string into a field, whereby the string is predetermined depending on what options are selected from two drop down menus?

This is so that a combination of two drop down menus creates a unique SKU for that product, and that string referred to as a SKU is inserted into the input value of the item_number variable and then passed to paypal during checkout.

I will use the example of selling tee-shirts. So the combinations will be black/small, black/large, white/small, & white/large. And each will have a unique SKU of TEESHIRT-BS, TEESHIRT-BL, TEESHIRT-WS & TEESHIRT-WL respectively.

Here is my HTML for the option selects, however, I think I need some JavaScript to insert the SKU into the value field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="colour"><b>select colour</b></><br>
  <select name="os0" >
  <option value="black">black</option> 
  <option value="white">white</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="size"><b>select size</b></><br>
  <select name="os1" >
  <option value="small">small</option>
  <option value="large">large</option>
</select>

<!-- SKU-->
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
var sizeList = document.getElementById('size');
var colorList = document.getElementById('color');
sizeList.onchange = function() {
    generateSku();
};
colorList.onchange = function() {
    generateSku();
};
function generateSku() {
    var selectedSize = sizeList.options[sizeList.selectedIndex].text;
    var selectedColor = colorList.options[colorList.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById('sku').value = 'TEESHIRT-' + selectedColor.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + selectedSize.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
}
generateSku();
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="colour"><b>select colour</b></><br>
  <select id="color" name="os0" >
  <option value="black">black</option> 
  <option value="white">white</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="size"><b>select size</b></><br>
  <select id="size" name="os1" >
  <option value="small">small</option>
  <option value="large">large</option>
</select>

<!-- SKU-->
<input id="sku" name="item_number" value="">
```

Comment: Thats cool thanks. Is there anyway of inserting these two added strings into the value="" field without using the button function, i.e. automatically?

Comment: Have edited the code. This should serve your purpose. And if it does, do mark it as correct please.

Comment: I might be being incredibly dense but the top code is javascript which I need to insert between the tags <script> </script> ? because I tried that and it didnt work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you need to place the top code inside <script> tags. Can you post your code here so that I can see how you are doing it?